# Using a Google Sheets script to make a form-style checkbox: how do I clear some ranges on multiple named sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

What if I want to clear additional sets of ranges on 'Target Sheet name' when I check the box on 'SurfaceApps'?

...here is my current code:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var r = ss.getActiveCell();
  if (r.getRow()== 4 && r.getColumn()== 4 && ss.getName()=='SurfaceApps') {
      // 2. If Edit is done in cell D4 then:
      ss.getRange('E6:E8').clearContent()
      ss.getRange('E14:E16').clearContent()  
      ss.getRange('E29:E30').clearContent()
  }
};
```

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

Clear all of the namedRanges on the current Sheet

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast("Entry");
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "SurfaceApps" && e.range.columnStart == 4 && e.range.rowStart == 4 && e.value == "TRUE" ) {
    //e.source.toast("Gate")
    sh.getNamedRanges().forEach(n => n.getRange().clearContent())
  }
}
```

Put Checkbox in D4

```
function putCheckInD4() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("SurfaceApps");
  sh.getRange("D4").insertCheckboxes();
}
```

- [onEdit.restrictions()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions)
- [range.insertCheckBoxes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#insertcheckboxes)

Answer (score 0):

Use `Sheet.getRangeList()`, like this:

```js
/**
* Simple trigger that runs each time the user manually edits the spreadsheet.
*
* @param {Object} e The onEdit() event object.
*/
function onEdit(e) {
  if (!e) throw new Error('Please do not run the onEdit(e) function in the script editor window.');
  let surfaceSheet;
  if (e.range.rowStart !== 4 || e.range.columnStart !== 4 || (surfaceSheet = e.range.getSheet()).getName() !== 'SurfaceApps') return;
  const targetSheet = e.source.getSheetByName('Target Sheet name');
  surfaceSheet.getRangeList(['E6:E8', 'E14:E16', 'E29:E30',]).clearContent();
  targetSheet.getRangeList(['A2:D4', 'X14:Z16', 'N29:O30',]).clearContent();
}
```

See [Sheet.getRangeList()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangelista1notations) and these [onEdit(e) optimization tips](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/155429/269219).